# Creating a Batch File for netcat

Tags: shell, batch-file, command-line, netcat

I want to implement the loop suggested as a solution in this question.([Send text file, line by line, with netcat](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13969817/send-text-file-line-by-line-with-netcat)).

```
while read x; do echo "$x" | nc host port; done < textfile
```

However, I have not created a script before. If someone knows how to make that simple script it would be a great help in getting me started. There are many examples but if I could see what I need done and reverse from there it would save a lot of time.

Thanks

Comment: Looks like you have tagged BASH by mistake. You wanted to type BATCH. Are you looking for something similar in Windows Batch file?

Comment: o correct i fixed that

Comment: netcat (nc) is not a built-in part of Windows so you would need to find a Win32 port of that. Aside from that, it would be helpful if you tell your goal, not your proposed solution.

Comment: i do have nc working on windows